# Are CSS box shadows officially unsupported for safari <select> fields?

Tags: html, css, safari

I've looked around but I cannot find any official statements regarding this issue.

The CSS box-shadow simply seems not to be supported in Safari Desktop (at least) for select elements.

Here is the JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t8uhwp3c/

For example this simple select does not show anything around the select element in Safari, but it shows the "shadow" properly in Chrome and Firefox:

```
<select style="box-shadow:0 0 0 20px red">
    <option>sfasdfasd</option>
</select>
```

This is important as I've seen box-shadows used input-feedback elements in several libraries, but I have not been able to find any reports of this issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `-webkit-appearance: none;` it will work